# Xamarin Listview child binding data not being sent back to View Modal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

We have a child (syncfusion) combobox control in our Xamarin project that resides inside a parent ListView element as shown below.

```
<ListView x:Name="llistView" ItemsSource="{Binding QuantityRows}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="30">
                        <Label Text="{Binding FieldDescription}"></Label>
                        <combobox:SfComboBox HeightRequest="40" x:Name="comboBox"  SelectedValue="{Binding ItemSelectedFromList}" IsVisible="False" DisplayMemberPath = "Name" DataSource="{Binding Listing, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <combobox:SfComboBox.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="combobox:SfComboBox"
                                Binding="{Binding FieldStringType}"
                                   Value="picklist">
                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </combobox:SfComboBox.Triggers>
                        </combobox:SfComboBox>
           </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As shown above, the combobox is bound to the viewmodel object ItemSelectedFromList.  When we run this with the combobox outside the listview, the two way binding is perfect, and it sends back the data back correctly. However, when the combobox is put into the listview, the data can be bound from the view modal, however, when a change is made on the combobox, the data never gets sent to the view model.  Looking closer, it seems that the event does get triggered, as we tried using the handler below, and found that it does get hit when an item is selected in the combobox

```
 private void DataPickList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

However the event never gets sent back to the actual viewmodel it's bound to, when it's inside the listview (Although, the event below does get hit when the control is not in the listview)

```
  FormattedOptions itemSelectedFromList;
        public FormattedOptions ItemSelectedFromList
        {
            get => this.itemSelectedFromList;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.itemSelectedFromList, value);
        }
```

Note that the issue is not specific to just this combolist control.  It seems that any control inside the listview doesn't get the data sent to the viewmodel.  Is there any fix or way around this?

UPDATE

As per the comment below, we added a x:Name and reference to the view model, however it the change event doesn't still doesn't get hit:

```
<combobox:SfComboBox HeightRequest="40" x:Name="comboBox" SelectedValue= "{Binding Source={x:Reference PagesName}, Path=BindingContext.ItemSelectedFromList}"  IsVisible="False" DisplayMemberPath = "Name" DataSource="{Binding Listing, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Which references the x:Name attribute on the page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             ....
             x:Name="PagesName">
```

Comment: When the ComboBox is nested within the DataTemplate, it's binding context is not the ViewModel, it gets the binding context from the items in the ListView, specifically an instance of whatever is in QuantityRows on the VM. To get around this, you can give the Page an x:Name, and update the binding like `SelectedValue={Binding Source={x:Reference PageName}, Path=BindingContext.ItemSelectedFromList}` This will try to bind all comboboxes in the listview to a single property on the VM, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you Max Hampton, however we tried doing this (I updated the question above to show the changes we made), however the event still isn't getting hit in the view model

Comment: I have not worked with syncfusion controls. What does the DataSource binding do? Is Listing a VM property or on the QuantityRows class? Is Listing a collection of FormattedOptions?

Comment: Hi Max, after more investigation, this seems to be an issue with the SyncFusion control, rather than specific to Xamarin itself, as their native controls seem to be binding properly.  I will follow up with them, and post an update once I get a response .